# Running a VM with old version of Ubuntu, what to use?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, container

I am currently using Ubuntu 20.04, but I still have my old PC with Ubuntu 10.04 installation, and I want to keep it available for occasional use (because there are some things in that version that worked good - and I'm used to the way they worked - and they don't work so good in the recent one). However, I don't want to keep the actual hardware, so I decided to convert the old Ubuntu 10.04 installation into a virtual machine and run it under my current system.

My current system is Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit, and the old one is 10.04 32-bit. What type of virtualization should I use? Do I need the full virtualization (I mean KVM - that was my first idea, as I already have some experience with it), or can I use something "lighter", ie. some container-based solution? I have no experience with containers, but as far as I understand, containers need to use the same kernel, so it seems to be impossible in my case? Am I right?

To clarify: I'm not asking about opinions "which virtualization is the best". I'm also not asking for any help with Ubuntu 10.04. I'm asking, **if it is possible** to run 32-bit kernel 2.6.32 (the one from Ubuntu 10.04) as a guest OS on current Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit kernel using anything "lighter" than full virtualization (mean: containers)?

Comment: Old versions of Ubuntu that have reached the end of life are off topic here.

Comment: @user68186 I am in fact not asking about the old version of Ubuntu; I am asking about the recent version (20.04), and what virtualization to use under it to run the old version. I don't consider this to be off-topic. Guest OS is off-topic, I agree, but my question is about host OS, not guest OS.

Comment: @Nmath I'm not asking about opinions. I only ask, whether in the specified configuration I **need** the full virtualization or the "light" virtualization (mean: containers) will work for me. It is a **fact** - it is either possible or not, and that's all I want to know. It's not an opinion.

Comment: @raj if you're taking a full disk image, you need full virtualization and data conversion.  The guest OS is offtopic though, regardless of the host OS you use.  You can't easily take a full disk and make it a VM or a container, though.  Not without interim media to store disk images and such on.  And then modification and revision of the disk image afterwards to make it 'bootable' in the VM.  It'd be easier for you to get the data you *need* off the old system (or take a ful disk image) and then access the disk image to get data you need, rather than 'running' the obsolete OS.

Comment: Containers always use the host kernel - you cannot run a different kernel using containerization.

Comment: If I wanted to do this, I'd take a Clonezilla clone of the old machine, and clone it into a virtualbox vm.

Comment: @ThomasWard I am very well aware of the possible problems with conversion of the physical installation into a VM and I think I can handle it :) I also don't ask for any help with this, regarding your note about guest OS being off-topic. I have all the data from old system moved into the new one long ago, but - as I mentioned - some things don't work correctly in the current release and the data is not handled properly (for example there are issues with the current LO vs the old OO). Therefore I need to actually be able to run the old system.